# So basically the info() command doesn't apply to tables that is directly pulled off by pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

url = "http://www.collegesimply.com/colleges/california/"
ca_colleges = pd.read_html(url)
ca_colleges.info()
```

The last line gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute info().
```

I'd like to know where did I get it wrong?

Comment: I don't understand *"directly pulled off"*, do you mean *"scraped"*?

Answer (score 0):

[`pd.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) returns a list of dataframes. So, you need to do it like this:

```
df = ca_colleges[0]
df.info()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, now it works. btw, may I ask what does [0] mean in this case? I ve only learned Python for less than 2 months, so forgive me if my question is too babystep.

Comment: you're accessing the first element of the list with the [0]